# IE not working in non-prod environment, Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, browser, angular5

In my local IE works just fine,

but after deployment through docker, IE throws couple of errors.

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error SCRIPT5007: The value of property is null or
>   undefined.

Enabled all the polyfills
animations
classlist 
es6/array
es7/array and the rest that are usually activated or imported by project.

but none works after deployment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can paste your full error code from console?

Comment: I assume that you actually used the `-prod` flag to deploy? `ng build -prod`.